# Change index of item in ImageComboBoxEdit

Tags: winforms, combobox, devexpress

I am populating dev express imagecombobox with some values. After the combo box is populated, I would like to change the order of the items.

Could this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this task is to clear existing items and repopulate them in the required order.